# Retrieving invocation details for failed Azure Function with App Insights

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I recently configured Application Insights on a few of my Azure functions which has been great and now I can see when and how often my function is failing. I've been logging some of the important data within the function that I've been able to see when I check the monitor tab on just the function like this,

**Function View**
[image: Azure Monitoring]

Part of the reason we configured App Insights is because we can only see a limited number of responses in this standard function view. I'm looking here to find Invocation details and Log information but can't seem to locate it. Am I looking in the wrong place?

**App Insights View**
[image: App Insights]

Answer (score 2):

You can find data generated by function invocations in the following tables:

- traces - Logs created by the runtime and by function code.
- requests - One for each function invocation.
- exceptions - Any exceptions thrown by the runtime.
- customMetrics - Count of successful and failing invocations, success rate, duration.
- customEvents - Events tracked by the runtime, for example: HTTP requests that trigger a function.
- performanceCounters - Info about the performance of the servers that the functions are running on.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#query-telemetry-data

So you can try to explore "requests" and "customEvents" tables.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking here to find Invocation details and Log information but can't seem to locate it.

You could open your function insights and click the **server request** to open the **operation details**.

When your function is failed, it would show failed request details as your invocation details.

Also you could click the **Exception** below the **Custom Data** to get the detailed log information and you could click “**…**” to get the total information.
[image]
[image]

You could compare it with log information in azure function.

[image]

**Note**: The invocation information in App Insights is different form with Function log information.So you may miss some information.

Comment: This unfortunately just gets me the exception information which I don't need. Most of all, getting the request body from the original request would answer my question but I'm not sure if that is possible now that I'm looking into this. Also the Invocation details are no longer available in my azure function since we've had other executions that force it off the page.

Comment: Actually, you could [monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#query-telemetry-data) your function with app insights. You could use [Application Insights Rest Api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/reference/get-query) to execute an Analytics query. If you would get the request body, you could use fiddler to capture it.